# modify pseudo select :after in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have defined a css like

```
.slidingTag li:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 3;
  height: 6px;
}
```

I want to change the height attribute dynamically from JS. I can get the property using

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.slidingTag'), 'li:after').getPropertyValue('height')
```

But I do not know how to change the height attribute. I tried to use `setProperty` but it seems there is no such function available for pseudo-classes. Any ideas let me know.

Comment: Pseudo-elements aren't in the DOM and so cannot be selected with Javascript. -

Comment: Ah...OK Perhaps this then - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666527/how-to-read-css-property-of-psuedo-class-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @torazaburo Well.. the OP said they want to "change the height", thus implying that they need to select the pseudo-element - which isn't possible.

Comment: Like any other CSS rule, you can change this using the CSS API.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo, is there any example you know about it? Thanks

Comment: A simple way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76331479/15155291

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If that style comes from a CSS file, you'll have to search for it in [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets), which will be messy.

If you are open to dynamically creating a `<style>` element containing that CSS instead, you can modify it programmatically.

```
var slidingTagLiAfterStyle = document.createElement("style");
slidingTagLiAfterStyle.innerHTML =
 ".slidingTag li:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: 3;
    height: 6px;
  }";
document.head.appendChild(slidingTagLiAfterStyle);

...

slidingTagLiAfterStyle.innerHTML = slidingTagLiAfterStyle.innerHTML.replace(/height: [0-9]+px/, "height: 12px"); // or whatever you want to set it to
```

Answer (score 8):

**Pseudo-elements like :before and :after are handled by CSS, not the DOM**. Because of this, you need to take a different approach.

**What you *can* do is find the CSS rule responsible for this pseudo-element, and change that.** You do this using CSSOM, which is a rather different API, even though you first get access to it from the DOM.

Unlike the DOM, CSS rules don't have ids or class names that can be searched for cleanly and quickly, so we have to search through the list of stylesheets and style rules. **This can be expensive, so if it's possible to search for it only once, I strongly recommend doing that**. Here's a quick-and-dirty way to do that:

```js
function getRuleWithSelector(selector) {
  var numSheets = document.styleSheets.length,
    numRules,
    sheetIndex,
    ruleIndex;
  // Search through the style sheets.
  for (sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < numSheets; sheetIndex += 1) {
    numRules = document.styleSheets[sheetIndex].cssRules.length;
    for (ruleIndex = 0; ruleIndex < numRules; ruleIndex += 1) {
      if (document.styleSheets[sheetIndex].cssRules[ruleIndex].selectorText === selector) {
        return document.styleSheets[sheetIndex].cssRules[ruleIndex];
      }
    }
  }
  // If we get this far, then the rule doesn't exist.
  // So the return value is undefined.
}

var afterSlidingTagRule = getRuleWithSelector('.slidingTag li::after');
console.debug(afterSlidingTagRule);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  afterSlidingTagRule.style.fontSize = "10px";
}, false);
```

```css
.slidingTag {
  color: blue;
}
.slidingTag li {
  color: green;
}
.slidingTag li:after {
  content: "World";
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slidingTag">
  <li class="selected">Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

**Once you've got the rule you need, the rest is very similar to working with getComputedStyle(), or with a DOM element's `style` attribute**. The snippet above does it in a DOMContentLoaded event handler, but you should be able to do it at any point once things have loaded.

There are a few caveats to be considered with this approach:

- **When you change a CSS rule, that change gets reflected in every element that the rule selects.** If you have a rule that affects many elements, and you need to change the way all those elements look, this is great. If you have a rule that affects many elements, but you only need to change the look of one of those elements, this isn't so good.
- **CSSOM's view of your selector text may not match what you wrote**. This comes up in this very example, in fact, because your selector should read `.slidingTag li::after` (note the extra colon). The browser corrects this when it parses your CSS, and this is what CSSOM knows to look for.
- **Just because a rule says something doesn't mean the element will display that way**. Anything that can override a CSS rule -element-specific styles, more specific rules elsewhere in the set, `!important` declarations, and so on- can also override your changes.
- **This isn't a substitute for `getComputedStyle()`**. That follows from the above: if something changes an element's presentation, that doesn't affect the underlying CSS rules. If anything, it is the opposite of `getComputedStyle()`: instead of *getting* what an element *currently* displays, it *sets* what certain elements *should* display (barring unforeseen circumstances).

Answer (score 5):

You can add an extra class to you element that have a different property on the `:after`, like:

**first you have this:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slidingTag">
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slidingTag li:after {
      content: '';
      z-index: 3;
      height: 6px;
    }
```

**then you got this:**

New class that will override the property `height` :

```
.slidingTag-modifier li:after {
   content: '';
  z-index: 3;
  height: 10px !important;
}
```

**final HTML:**

```
<div class="slidingTag slidingTag-modifier">
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
</div>
```

**To do that with javascript:**

```
var element = document.querySelector('.slidingTag');
//use this instruction wherever you want to add the new class that will override the property
element.classList.add('slidingTag-modifier'); 
//works only on recent browsers
```

cheers!