# Modify the width of :after pseudo CSS element from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically change the width of an element in :after. But it is not reflecting. Can someone please help!

```js
$(function(){
var a=20;
$(".progress:after").width(a+"%"); 
// This is not showing 20%. Still shows 50% which was coded in CSS
});
```

```css
.progress {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
.progress:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    background:black;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left:0; 
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Here is the [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9px8p/230/) to JSFidle

Comment: You cannot use `$(".progress:after")` as a selector.

Comment: Question.. What is the purpose of the psuedo? Do you have dynamic content?

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260296/modify-pseudo-select-after-in-javascript

Comment: Even better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Comment: @Cam: I am trying to change the width so as to make it function like a progress bar.

Comment: @Kshri you could simply adjust the class name, and have unique classes. Or you could have a proper element and change it's width instead of using a pseudo element.

Comment: @All: I have tried all of the ones in stackoverflow! None of them actually worked!

Comment: @Kshri then try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/huw9c3n6/

Comment: @Twisty: That really helped! Thank you so much

Comment: @Kshri welcome, Some more thought on it: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/huw9c3n6/1/

Comment: @Twisty: Looks brilliant :)

Comment: @Kshri also consider jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: @Twisty: I did think about that but the whole logic is already implemented using <meter>. But it looks like <meter> is not supported in Safari browser. So this is an alternate solution which runs just in safari without complicating existing things much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the, *now available*, html5 [`progress` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress).

```js
$(function() {
  var a = 20;
  $("progress").prop('value', a);
});
```

```css
progress {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    background:transparent;
}
::-webkit-progress-bar{background:transparent;}

::-moz-progress-bar{background-color:black;}
::-ms-fill{background-color:black;}
::-webkit-progress-value{background-color:black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress value="50" max="100"></progress>
```