# Extract text from one paragraph and insert into another

Tags: jquery

Expanding on [How to get a text before given element using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543648/how-to-get-a-text-before-given-element-using-jquery) - how does one actually insert this text into another paragraph?

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/fqwow5rr/

HTML:

```
<p>Text here <a href="#">URL</a></p>

<!-- Should be:

<p>Text here</p>
<p><a href="#">URL</a></p>

-->
```

JS:

```
var text = $('a').parent().html();
var regex = /(.*)<a/;

text = text.match(regex)[1];

console.log('Extracted text: ' + text);

# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
text.clone().append('<p></p>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override `text` variable with a string value. See fixed example:

```js
var $text = $('a').parent();
var regex = /(.*)<a/;

var eText = $text.html().match(regex)[1];

console.log('Extracted text: ' + eText);

$text.after($('<p>', {
  text: eText
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text here <a href="#">URL</a>
</p>
```

If you only want to move the link element (`a`), just take it and insert it into the new paragraph:

```js
var $a = $('a');
var $text = $('a').parent();

$text.after($('<p>', {
  html: $a[0].outerHTML
}));
$a.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text here <a href="#">URL</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! Cheers, this should be exactly what I need. For what it's worth here's the actual use case: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/o4uguntu/5/

Comment: @MarkBoulder Great. :-)

Comment: Any chance you can give me some feedback on http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/o4uguntu/10/ ?

Comment: @MarkBoulder Ask a new question for that. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: It should all be well explained in that fiddle.

Comment: @MarkBoulder I'd really recommend asking a new question about that. It's better to discuss there and keep the side clean.

Comment: You're right. I have created the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424984/extract-text-from-one-paragraph-and-insert-into-another-pt-2