# How to select all content of an element which are behind a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<tr>
   <td class="CT">
      anything –
      <span class="cu">
         <a href="#"></a>
      </span> – 
      <span class="dt">content</span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to just select `anything` from all of that HTML code. How? I just can select its text:

```
$('tr').text();
/* but the way, there is two function that I feel they can be useful:
   1. closest()
   2. siblings() */
```

Well, is there any solution?

**Note:** I can't use `replace()`, because sometimes there is a different content for `<span>` or a href for `<a>`.

---

**Edit:** `anything` is not just a string. It can be one of these:

`anything` = `this is a <a href="www.example.com">test</a>`

`anything` = `hello, how are you`

`anything` = `<a href="www.example.com">test1</a> and <a href="www.example.com">test2</a>`

Actually I want all content of `td.CT` behind `<span class="cu">`. In reality, it is the content of a comment (for editing it) and I want to set it in the textarea (again, for editing it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543648/how-to-get-a-text-before-given-element-using-jquery

Comment: So basically you're asking how to target a `textNode` with jQuery? ...... duplicate !

Comment: @adeneo yes, I just want to select `anything`.

Comment: `$('.CT').get(0).nextSibling`

Comment: @adeneo thanks, but the output of your code is `null`.

Comment: It needs to be `firstChild` not `nextSibling`, it returns `null` because `td.CT` doesn't have any siblings.

Comment: ^ there's that, one could also do `$('.cu').get(0).previousSibling`

Comment: Or without jQuery - `document.querySelector('.CT').firstChild.textContent.trim()`

Comment: Or with jQuery -> `$('.CT').contents().first()`

Comment: @adeneo very thanks :-) it works.

Comment: @JoshCrozier thanks, but can you please tell me how can I use `rtrim()` in javascript/jquery? actually I need to remove hyphen `–` in the end of string that I selected.

Comment: @stack `document.querySelector('.CT').firstChild.textContent.trim().replace(/–$/, '');`

Comment: @JoshCrozier perfect..! and sorry for asking again, but according to reality, I have to use `$(this).closest(".CT")` instead of `document.querySelector('.CT')`. Well, I tested and it didn't work. Now I want to know can I use `closest()` in your code?

Comment: @stack It depends. What is `this`?

Comment: @JoshCrozier `this` is `<a href="#"></a>` in the my example.

Comment: It's still the same `$(this).closest(".CT").contents().get(0).textContent ... etc`

Comment: @adeneo Thanks pal. :*

Comment: @adeneo well, I am really ashamed for ping you again, but I updated my question. If you have some free time, please take a look at it. (also sorry for asking my question badly in first)

Comment: And you @JoshCrozier, I'm embarrassed to ping you again. But sorry, I updated my question. If you have some free time, please take a look at it. (also sorry for asking my question badly in first)

Comment: Your three "anything" examples are very different from each other. (1) A text node followed by an `<a>` node; (2) a text node; (3) two `<a>` nodes with a text node in between. So what qualifies as "anything"? What rule do you want to be encoded?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the only clue is: all content before (behind or in the top of) `span.cu`.

Comment: OK, that's a workable rule.

Comment: @adeneo so, my new version of question is impossible? if yes, please tell me to I forget it. tnx

Comment: Sure it's possible, just remove everything before `.cu`, then prepend the new content, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/v2r4z407/1/

Comment: Oh wait, messed up a bit there, should be like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v2r4z407/2/**

Comment: @adeneo seems near to what I want. look, do you know what I want exactly? when you click on the "edit" in the front of your comment in SO, what happens? A textarea will be made containing your comment. Now I want to select current user's comment and set it to textarea. Just I want to select current-his-comment-from-html. It can be contains a string plus a link. So please and please just show me a fiddle with this outpit: `<a href="www.example.com">test1</a> and <a href="www.example.com">test2</a>` *(for third structure)* really and really tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a (hacky) way to extract "anything" before the `<span class="cu">` node.

- Find all of the td's contents
- Convert from jQuery collection to a js array
- Reduce the array such that all nodes up to but not including `<span class="cu">` are pushed onto an array.
- Wrap the array of nodes in `$()` to form a jQuery collection.
- Finally append the collection to some DOM container to make the result visible.

```
var $myFragment = $($(".CT").contents().get().reduce(function(obj, node) {
    if($(this).is("span.cu")) {
        obj.stop = true;
    }
    if(!obj.stop) {
        obj.nodes.push(node);
    }
    return obj;
}, {nodes:[], stop:false}).nodes);

// then
$("#myResult").append($myFragment);

// or maybe
//$("#myResult").append($myFragment.text());
```

I'm sure there's a simpler way but I can't think of it right now.

DEMOS:

- Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/1xonqeob/1/
- Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/1xonqeob/2/
- Example 3: http://jsfiddle.net/1xonqeob/3/

---

And here's that simpler way I was talking about :

```
var $myFragment = $(".CT").contents().filter(function(i, node) {
  return !$(node).prevAll().addBack().filter("span.cu").length;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1xonqeob/4/

---

And here's something more generic; a jQuery plugin `.prevAllNodes()`, which :

- operates on the element before which nodes are to be found.
- accepts a nodeType or array of nodeTypes to be found. Pass nothing or `[]` to find all nodeTypes.
- returns a jQuery collection of nodes.

```
// *****************************************************
// A jQuery plugin to find DOM nodes of specified types 
// before the first element in a jQuery collection.
// *****************************************************
$.fn.prevAllNodes = function(types) {
    types = types || [];
    if(!$.isArray(types)) types = [types];
    var that = this.eq(0);
    var nodes = that.parent().contents().get().reduce(function(nodes, node) {
        nodes.stop = nodes.stop || (node == that.get(0));
        return nodes.stop ? nodes : nodes.concat(node);
    }, []).filter(function(node) {
        return types.length == 0 || $.inArray(node.nodeType, types) > -1;
    });
    return $(nodes);
}
```

Use as follows :

```
var $commentsNodes = $(".CT span.cu").prevAllNodes([Node.COMMENT_NODE]); 

// $commentsNodes is a jQuery collection
// To read comments' text, you need to know to use the `.nodeValue` property. jQuery's $(commentNode).text() will not work.
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/1xonqeob/5/

*$.fn.nextAllNodes() would be very similar*

Comment: Thanks, But I tested it and there isn't any output. Can you please add a fiddle to your answer?

Comment: It was just a simple coding error. Take another look - links to fiddles added.

Comment: And I found time to write something you might find even more useful - a generic jQuery plugin - `.prevAllNodes()`, added above.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `contents().first().text()` just like **@adeneo** mentioned in comment :

```js
$('#result').text( $(".CT").contents().first().text().trim().replace(/–$/, '') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <td class="CT">
      anything – 
      <span class="cu">
         <a href="#"></a>
      </span> – 
      <span class="dt">content</span>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>
Output (<span id='result'></span>)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, But I want just `anything` not `anything – – content`.

Comment: You're welcome, check my update, the code now will return `anything`.

Comment: Thanks. +1. But actually I updated my question. (sorry for asking my question badly in first)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach to solve this problem. The code gets *any* number of nodes (including comments and text) before the `span.cu` element.

I moved the target elements to a new `<div>` for demonstration purposes.

```js
var tdContents = $('td.CT').contents();
var cu = $('span.cu');
var cuPosition;

// get the position of the span.cu element
tdContents.each(function(i, el) {
  if (el == cu[0]) {
    cuPosition = i;
  }
});

// get rid of span.cu and following nodes
var result = tdContents.slice(0, cuPosition - 1);

// put the interesting content in another div
result.appendTo('#result');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="CT">
      anything – <a style="color: red">(really)</a>
      <span class="cu">
         <a href="#"></a>
      </span> – 
      <span class="dt">content</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>
```