# Extract the text in a Element then append it to an attribute with using jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, attributes, clone, extract

I'm piggy-backing on this link...
[Extract the Text in a Element with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017330/extract-the-text-in-a-element-with-jquery)

I like to extract the text in a element then append it to an attribute like so..

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text;
    $(".parent span").contents().each(function(i) {
        if(this.nodeName == "#text") text = $(this).text();   
        $(".child").attr("ref", text);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <span><strong>bla bla bla</strong>Child-1</span> </div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"> </div>
  <span><strong>bla bla bla</strong>Child-2</span> 
</div>
```

I keep getting "Child-1" in each parent's ref.

Comment: `$('#bla2').attr({ref:$('#bla').text()});`

Comment: What text you want to extract and append it where ? And whats reason for doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.child").each(function() {
        var text = "";
        $(this).next("span").contents().each(function(i) {
            if(this.nodeName == "#text") text += $(this).text();
        });
        $(this).parent().attr("ref", text);
    });
});
```

Note: I used the accepted answer in the linked question for obtaining the desired text from the first `div`.

Comment: @user952851 - Oops, I had `+=` instead of the correct `+`. Try it again.

Comment: It's showing up this... <div id="bla2" ref="undefinedI want this text"> </div>

Comment: But... the problem now is it's not grabbing the element for each set$(document).ready(function() {
    var text;
    $(".bla span").contents().each(function(i) {
        if(this.nodeName == "#text") text = $(this).text();   
  $(".bla2").attr("ref", text);
    });
});

Comment: @user952851 - I'm not sure if I'm understanding you, but if I am, the edited code should work.

Comment: I edited my question.. please look above ^^^. I'm trying to have each parent's child different from one of another.

Comment: @user952851 - So do you want the first parent `div` to have a `class` or "Child-1" and the second parent `div` to have a `class` or "Child-2"?

Comment: I'm just looking for the ref name to be different for each Parent

Comment: to answer your question.. yes I do

Comment: And it should continue if I keep adding more parents, which will lead to Child-1, Child-2, Child-3, Child-4, and so on

Comment: Jeff... How come it doesn't work in IE? It works perfectly in FF, Chrome, etc